# How to open WhatsApp Contact screen/acitivity in Android using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I used to be able to open the Contact Screen/Activity (ContactPicker) by this intent:

```
sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
```

This does not seem to work any longer and I get the following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.whatsapp/com.whatsapp.ContactPicker}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Is this still possible? Is this done using a different intent? If yes, someone who can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it:

```
com.whatsapp.contact.picker.ContactPicker
```